# Globalization's effects on workers

Tags: economy

due to globalization, are there any affects of me purchasing clothes on people who manufacture these clothes. in other words, are there any political implications for my consumption of clothes?

Comment: In the broadest definition, virtually anything that happens has political implications on almost anything else. The question is what order the effect is and what is its magnitude.

Comment: This is an impossibly complex question for a QA site. The effects of globalization...both good and bad...are immense. There are all all sorts of research, analysis, opinion, data, spin, literature, college courses, thesis, etc on this topic with no cut and dried answer.

Answer (score 2):

There is one very simple effect, you helped give the workers who made those clothes a job. Globalization has allowed people in developing countries to move from the extreme poverty of subsistence agriculture to jobs which may seem low paying by western standards, but actually provide much more security and opportunities, especially for their children. Globalization through open trade and market reforms has brought about [a billion people](http://www.economist.com/news/leaders/21578665-nearly-1-billion-people-have-been-taken-out-extreme-poverty-20-years-world-should-aim) in the developing world out of extreme poverty. Here's a specific example in [Bangladesh](http://www.npr.org/sections/money/2013/12/03/247360855/two-sisters-a-small-room-and-the-world-behind-a-t-shirt).

Another effect of buying imported clothes is that you may be contributing to the shift in your own country away from the garment industry. In many countries like the United States, the economy has been moving away from making its own clothing and towards other industries like services and technology. The people who used to make clothes in the United States may have to go back to school for technical training, or switch to low skill jobs in the service sector. Former garment industry workers could lose out in this transition, especially in the short run, but in most economists see the movement of countries towards producing things they have [comparative advantage](http://www.econlib.org/library/Topics/Details/comparativeadvantage.html) in producing to be a good thing for consumers overall.

A political implication of the above trend is that if there are existing garment producers in your country, they may try to get politicians to enact tariffs (taxes on imports) to try to make you buy their goods instead of the less expensive ones from abroad. Economists are quite consistent in [agreeing that](http://gregmankiw.blogspot.com/2009/02/news-flash-economists-agree.html) such "tariffs and import quotas usually reduce general economic welfare."

Comment: It's not nearly that simple. For every job you may have helped create, you may also be taking away another.

Comment: @blip can you be more specific with your criticism? My second 2 paragraphs talk about the fact that some people may lose their jobs, what part of that explanation was incorrect or incomplete?

Comment: My comment was directed at the "one very simple effect". I consider that an overstatement. I'd use the wording of "one of many complex effects..."